# Bootstrap: Because when I select a checkbox, another is marked? with php echo

Tags: php, checkbox

I am working on a form for my website, I am using Bootstrap 4.2 to create a checkbox system with PHP echo, but it turns out that when I select, for example, in this case, when I select "Test 1" or "Test 2 "is marked" Test 3 "

CODE:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
    
  <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline1">
    
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1"><?php echo $categoria['name']; ?></label>
    
</div>
                <?php else: ?>
          
          
          
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
    
  <input id="defaultInline1" selected value="<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" name="topic_id[]" class="custom-control-input">
    
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1"><?php echo $categoria['name']; ?></label>
    
</div>
          
          
          
                <?php endif; ?>
            
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Make sure you are using unique `id` for each checkbox for each HTML element, if this is a different chose make like that: `id="defaultInline-<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>"`. Also you missed `name` value attribute, which can cause that only `topic_id[]` checkbox will be visible on time when you submit.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Hello, I tried it and the problem was solved, however now when I click on the check it does not work and you have to move the mouse a little to the right to make it work, how can I solve it?

Comment: I just checked your code on jsfiddle and everything works as expected. Check your styles, may be some conflicts appear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using unique `id` for each checkbox for each `HTML` element, if this is a different chose - make like that: `id="defaultInline-<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>"`.
Also you missed name value attribute, which can cause that only `topic_id[]` checkbox will be **visible** on time when you submit.

**Here is the working example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        
      <input id="defaultInline1" value="1" type="checkbox" name="topic_id[]" class="custom-control-input">
        
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">Label1</label>
        
    </div>
              
              
              
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
        
      <input id="defaultInline12" value="2" type="checkbox" name="topic_id[]" class="custom-control-input">
        
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline12">label2</label>
        
    </div>
```